# Set default processor properties in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I'd like to set the default value of `PutS3Object`'s `EndpointOverride` property to a MinIO cluster.

Is it possible in NIFI to set default values for certain processor properties?

Comment: Not possible when you make a new processor. maybe you should use template ?

Comment: That's disappointing, it'd be nice to set sane defaults for users 90% of the time on individual processors (like endpointOverride). Wanted to confirm it wasn't possible, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason this is not available is because it would get complicated very fast when multiple people work in nifi and start to see defaults change without notice.

However, there use of variables may help with this.

You could use the variable registry to define the exact place you want to connect to, and refer to the variable every time instead of putting in the complete URL.

An added benefit would be that it becomes much easier to move flows to a different environment, if you go from dev to prod you probably want to change as little as possible, and variables help with this where defaults could stimulate hardcoding links into every individual processor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible when you use a new processor.

You can use template instead.

create a template from a existing processor with default value :

[image]

user will be able to use your template with default value :

[image]